# Only run knitr on parts of Rnw file that have changed

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave, rnw

Say I have two code blocks contained within an `Rnw` file, `code_block_1` and `code_block_2`. Lets say I make to changes to `code_block_1` but `code_block_2` remains unchanged.

I'm using `knitr` to convert the `Rnw` file to a `tex` file. Because `code_block_2` has remained unchanged, can I have `knitr` only evaluate and run `code_block_1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check out `knitr`'s options here: http://yihui.name/knitr/options/. I think what you're looking for is the `cache` option. Try this small example and notice that the times change from one run to the other only for the chunk where you've actually changed the code:

First run:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<code_block_1, cache=TRUE>>=
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10)
summary(x)
Sys.time()
@

<<code_block_2, cache=TRUE>>=
set.seed(123)
y <- rnorm(10)
summary(y)
Sys.time()
@

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: im1]

Second run (after adding a comment in the second chunk):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<code_block_1, cache=TRUE>>=
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10)
summary(x)
Sys.time()
@

<<code_block_2, cache=TRUE>>=
# Just added a comment in this chunk
set.seed(123)
y <- rnorm(10)
summary(y)
Sys.time()
@

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: im2]